# Django many-to-many 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: django

I have following Django models:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
       ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(
           'foo.Ingredient',
            through='RecipeIngredient',
            through_fields=('recipe', 'ingredient')
       )

class RecipeIngredient(models.Model):

    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, blank=True, null=True)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey('foo.Ingredient', blank=True, null=True)
```

Which produces an error:

```
name = model._meta.db_table
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

It looks like ORM can't find `foo.Ingredient` model and interprets it like str (but `ForeginKey` works fine)

I also tried use `through='current.RecipeIngredient`, which produces:

```
sec_column = fk.m2m_column_name()
AttributeError: 'ManyToManyField' object has no attribute 'm2m_column_name'
```

How to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: This bug seems related: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25292

Comment: This is almost certainly related to the bug report linked above, which was closed a mere 5 days ago. OP should update to the absolute latest Django if possible, and may have to stop using `through_fields` if not. @knbk should make that comment an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AttributeError: 'str'` can be solved by replacing `through='RecipeIngredient'` with `through='current_app.RecipeIngredient' (see https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25292)

AttributeError: 'ManyToManyField' object has no attribute 'm2m_column_name' can be solved by placing Ingredient and recipe to same app.

But update to Django 1.9.7 is best way.